# Flutter - The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. - record not displayed with the widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a compound query. If this one works, then I want to display the results in a listView.builder.
The records are not displayed properly. I do not understand why. I must display the name field of each document find using the query. I have tried different options, but the result is also an error.
Thank you.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoadDataFromFirestore extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadDataFromFirestore({super.key});

  @override
 State<LoadDataFromFirestore> createState() => _LoadDataFromFirestoreState();
}

class _LoadDataFromFirestoreState extends State<LoadDataFromFirestore> {

  QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myQuery().then((results) {
      setState(() {
        querySnapshot = results;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _showDrivers(),
    );
  }

  Widget _showDrivers() {

    if (querySnapshot != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        primary: false,
        itemCount: querySnapshot?.docs.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              Text(querySnapshot!.docs[i].data().toString()),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  }

  Future myQuery () async{
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';

    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    Query statusQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Next Action');
    Query importantQuery = statusQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: 'False');

    final snapshot = await importantQuery.get();

    final data = snapshot.docs;
    if(data.isNotEmpty){
      for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
        print(data[i].data());
        return Text(data[i]['name']);
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any valid response from that snapshot? Also, have you tried removing that function _showDrivers() and using the widget inside build directly?

Comment: Yes. I am getting the records I should get when I use the snapshot. I have printed the results. To your second question, my answer is no. Not sure to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't test this, my guess is that the view is not refreshing properly since you used an function to get that widget.
Also you're returning an widget (Text) instead of the expected response that is of type QuerySnapshot.
Also you're returning `data` at the end which is a List and not the snapshot.

Go ahead and try this please:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoadDataFromFirestore extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadDataFromFirestore({super.key});

  @override
 State<LoadDataFromFirestore> createState() => _LoadDataFromFirestoreState();
}

class _LoadDataFromFirestoreState extends State<LoadDataFromFirestore> {

  QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myQuery().then((results) {
      setState(() {
        querySnapshot = results;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: querySnapshot != null ? ListView.builder(
        primary: false,
        itemCount: querySnapshot?.docs.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ListTile(
           title: Text(querySnapshot!.docs[i].data().toString()),
          );
        },
      ) : Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    );
  }

  Future myQuery () async{
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';

    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    Query statusQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Next Action');
    Query importantQuery = statusQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: 'False');

    final snapshot = await importantQuery.get();

    final data = snapshot.docs;
    if(data.isNotEmpty){
      //for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
      //  print(data[i].data());
      //  return Text(data[i]['name']);
      //}
      return snapshot;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried. I am getting an error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Text' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' and also I am getting the circular progress indicator turning without stopping

Comment: I guess I figured out what's going on, you're returning a Widget (text) instead of raw data. Just commented those few lines, try it out. @LaurentThomas

Comment: Also, what type is `snapshot.docs`? Because you're assigning it to `QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;` and they must be same type (QuerySnapshot)

Comment: I am getting an other error: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' - About your question, I am not sure. I am a newbie with flutter

Comment: @LaurentThomas try now, I 've changed the object being returned to the raw Snapshot at the end instead of `snapshot.docs`. That should do it

Comment: Thank you. Now, it displays all the data. Please, can you confirm if this is correct? ListView(
                    children:
                      [Text(querySnapshot!.docs[i].data('name').toString()),]), - Thank you

Comment: @LaurentThomas No, ListView works best with ListTile, I have changed that line, check it out. If that answers your question please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Many thanks. My last question if I can I just want to get the id and the name field. But when I type 'name' it is not displayed. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @LaurentThomas check this out https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querysnapshot